# Organising XCUITest with Enums in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, testing, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

So I was reading an  article: https://shashikantjagtap.net/organising-xcuielements-with-swift-enumerations/

It suggests an way to organize XCUItest as follows:

```
enum HomeScreen: String {
    case guestButton = "Hello"
    case registerButton = "Register"
    case loginButton = "Login"
    case welcomeText = "Welcome"
    case introText = "Introduction to app"
    var element: XCUIElement {
        if buttonElements.contains(self) {
            return XCUIApplication().buttons[self.rawValue]
        }
        if textElements.contains(self) {
            return XCUIApplication().staticTexts[self.rawValue]
        }
        fatalError("Element not found")
    }
 
    private var buttonElements: [HomeScreen] {
        return [.guestButton, .registerButton, .loginButton]
    }
 
    private var textElements: [HomeScreen] {
        return [.welcomeText, .introText]
    }
}
```

But say I an element that act as a checkmark and is a child of a specific component. Can you add that image to this enum?

The things I wanna check is:

```
app.buttons["button_with_checkmark_1"].images["dynamic_image_checkmark"].exists
app.buttons["button_with_checkmark_2"].images["dynamic_image_checkmark"].exists
app.buttons["button_with_checkmark_3"].images["dynamic_image_checkmark"].exists
```

But how can you get access to the image with the structure suggested above?

Comment: I inherited a framework using this architecture and would caution you from using it. Enums are great, but they have their limits, and IMO a traditional page object model is more flexible and powerful. This is nice and simple if you're doing nice and simple things, but it doesn't scale very well.

Comment: I agree, this is a lot of boilerplate code and isn't achieving much, you are better off using a more scalable architecture (you've already run into a problem this isn't able to solve). I suggest the Page Object Model, or the Screenplay pattern if you want to do something modern. Page Object Model in Swift: https://qualitytesting.tumblr.com/post/144462182209/xctest-and-the-page-object-model, Screenplay in Swift: https://qualitytesting.tumblr.com/post/173669653014/what-is-the-screenplay-pattern-part-1-of-3

Comment: In addition to what other commenters said, be aware that `XCUIApplication` is not a singleton and you may want to rethink using it like in the example you posted.